# How can I use the SQL IN operator with FMDB for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode4.3, fmdb

I've been trying to get the IN operator to work with FMDB but have had 
zero luck.  I've tried many different google searches and the only 
relevant post I found was on Stack Overflow but it is returning 0 
records. 
[Passing an array to sqlite WHERE IN clause via FMDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383684/passing-an-array-to-sqlite)...

If there are any existing examples or if someone knows how to do this, 
I would greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue, and I believe I figured it out, at least for my own app.  First, structure your query like so, matching the number of question marks as the amount of data in the array:

NSString *getDataSql = @"SELECT * FROM data WHERE dataID IN (?, ?, ?)";

Then use the executeQuery:withArgumentsInArray call:

FMResultSet *results = [database executeQuery:getDataSql withArgumentsInArray:dataIDs];

In my case, I had an array of NSString objects inside the NSArray named dataIDs.  I tried all sorts of things to get this call working, but with this combination of sql / function, I was able to get results.

Comment: I had to do this like you suggested because my column was of integer type. Thanks