# SQL WHERE IN Clause not working - FMDB - passing a comma separated string

Tags: ios, sqlite, where-clause, fmdb, clause

I have searched through all the questions, but did not find an answer yet. The closest I came to was this [Passing an array to sqlite WHERE IN clause via FMDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383684/passing-an-array-to-sqlite-where-in-clause-via-fmdb) . However, the answer suggested did not seem to work. The command does not throw any error, however it does not perform the intended operation (e.g. DELETE) either.
Here's what I am trying to do :

```
[myDB executeUpdateWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM table WHERE row_id IN (%@)",rowIdsToBeDeleted];
```

rowIdsToBeDeleted is a comma seperated NSString containing rowIds as NSNumber objects, e.g.

```
1000,1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008,1009,1010,1011,1012
```

I even tried using the executeUpdate, but no luck.
Could any of you please help ?

Comment: Refer this answer this may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/49699721/3777992

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If that method is anything like the NSPredicate syntax, simply remove the parenthesis (they are handled for you (and pass in a collection instead of a string):

```
NSArray *ids = [rowIdsToBeDeleted componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
[myDB executeUpdateWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM table WHERE row_id IN %@",ids];
```

## edit

Also, usually you pass in an actual collection object (not a string)... above edited to reflect

Comment: I am sending a NSString containing CS NSNumber objects (it's not NSPredicate like/sending NSNumbers since ints do not work on FMDB). However, I tried your solution and it gives the following error (FMDB error code 1, Syntax error): `near "?": syntax error`

Comment: Thanks, I will try that too. However, there was one more solution posted by some one else, but guess he deleted that. Thanks to him, the following worked like a charm: 
    `[myDB executeUpdateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM table WHERE row_id IN (%@)",rowIdsToBeDeleted]];`

Answer (score 4):

You could do simply:

```
[myDB executeUpdate:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM table WHERE row_id IN (%@)",rowIdsToBeDeleted]];
```

---

Despite what one might otherwise infer from the method name, the `executeUpdateWithFormat` method does *not* perform traditional `printf`-style formatting. Behind the scenes, what it really does is iterate through the format strings, replacing the printf-style strings with `?` placeholders, and then try to the appropriate `sqlite3_bind_xxx` function to bind the values to those placeholders.

This implementation of `executeUpdateWithFormat` introduces all sorts of subtle issues. (Because of this, it is likely to be deprecated in future FMDB versions.)  In this particular case, the problem is that `sqlite3_bind_xxx` can not bind a comma separated string as an array of values to be bound to a single `?` placeholder.

Generally one should avoid using `stringWithFormat` (or Swift string interpolation) to build SQL statements to be passed to FMDB or SQLite because if done improperly, you can be exposed to SQL injection attacks and/or fail if you fail to properly escape string values. But this example, where you want to test to see if some numeric value is within a set of numeric values, is an exception to that rule and you can use `stringWithFormat` as shown above.

Comment: executeUpdateWithFormat is actually not the same as passing a formatted string to executeUpdate. Unfortunately. Tried the former variation and it didn't work since it tried to convert everything to sql bindings.

Comment: The simple NSString stringWithFormat does work. I can confirm that.

Comment: The reason why executeUpdateWithFormat is different from executeUpdate is that the variable replacement is done by SQLite, and it will sanitize the input, so a string with commas in it is not treated as multiple values, but one big string value with commas in it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've clarified my answer to explain why `executeUpdateWithFormat` doesn't work, whereas `stringWithFormat` in conjunction with `executeUpdate` does.